# Can i give foreign key relationships of ODBC tables from ms sql to ms access

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access, sql

I have a question regarding the ODBC relationships between SQL and MS ACCESS as i have migrated several tables from SQL to ms access and i performed some operations but the problem occured in relationships as i cannot give exact foreign key relations and one to many and many to many relations i want to know whether it is possible to give relations between ODBC tables of MS ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define foreign key relationships in Access. As long as you aren't doing anything particularly unusual SQL Server relationships normally translate just fine to MS Access relationships.

Here are some excepts from this link:

[Microsoft: How to define relationships between tables in an Access database](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/304466)

> A one-to-many relationship is the most common kind of relationship. In
>   this kind of relationship, a row in table A can have many matching
>   rows in table B. But a row in table B can have only one matching row
>   in table A. ... In the relationship window in Access, the primary key
>   side of a one-to-many relationship is denoted by a number 1. The
>   foreign key side of a relationship is denoted by an infinity symbol.
>
> In a many-to-many relationship, a row in table A can have many
>   matching rows in table B, and vice versa. You create such a
>   relationship by defining a third table that is called a junction
>   table. The primary key of the junction table consists of the foreign
>   keys from both table A and table B. For example, the "Authors" table
>   and the "Titles" table have a many-to-many relationship that is
>   defined by a one-to-many relationship from each of these tables to the
>   "TitleAuthors" table. The primary key of the "TitleAuthors" table is
>   the combination of the au_ID column (the "Authors" table’s primary
>   key) and the title_ID column (the "Titles" table’s primary key).

Comment: Thank you for you response but iam asking it for ODBC tables which i took from the SQL SERVER and i think this is possible but in diferent way

Comment: The tables aren't ODBC they are Access, ODBC is the compatibility layer you're using to communicate with them. Are you asking How to create a relationship? What tool are you using to create the Access tables?

Comment: Ya exactly they are access odbc tables but the relationships with normal tables differ with odbc tables of access but i found how to figure out the problem thank you :)